# Motherboard beep on Windows CE

Tags: c++, compact-framework, windows-ce, beep

I wish to emit a "beep" from the motherboard of a system running Windows CE. Most information / code I have come across use `MessageBeep` which, from what I can tell, attempts to use the soundcard as opposed to the hardware on the motherboard.

I am using C++ but can you C#.NET if required.
I am running Windows CE 6 on a small PC and not a hand held device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried printing a [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)?

```
cout << '\a';
```

Answer (score 2):

If the OS audio driver isn't plumbed down to that device (and it sounds like it isn't since it's coming from the sound card's device) then you're going to have to go directly to it with ASM code.  You might even have to put it into a driver (user mode should work fine) in order to get access to the hardware.

Assuming you're on an X86 (I've never seen an ARM device with a speaker on the motherboard) then the code is no different than that used by someone running any other OS (since you're going direct to the hardware).  A quick search for "x86 beep in asm" turned up a couple promising leads.